# ¿Como buscar por un criterio en la base de datos con symfony?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, symfony

Buenas este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Reference\Url;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

class TrazaCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'Traza';
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        parent::__construct(self::$defaultName);
    }
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Add a short description for your command')
            ->addArgument('arg1', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description')
            ->addOption('option1', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Option description')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        $manager=fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\sgisi-master\public\x.txt','r');
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:URLExcluir');
        while (!feof($manager)){
            $cadena= fgets($manager);
            $cadena = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $cadena);
            $array=explode(" ", $cadena);
            if($array[3] == "TCP_MISS/200"){
                $url = ($array[6]);
                $urldb = $repository->findOneBy(URL,$url);
                if (null != $urldb){
                    print_r ($array);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En la linea :
 $urldb = $repository->findOneByURL($url); obtengo este error

```
Entity 'App\Entity\URLExcluir' has no field 'uRL'. You can therefore not ca
  ll 'findOneByURL' on the entities' repository
```

y la cambie por este   $urldb = $repository->findOneBy(Url,$url);y ahora sale esto

```
 Warning: Use of undefined constant URL - assumed 'URL' (this will throw an
  Error in a future version of PHP)
```

y ya no se como mas poner para que me busque esa url en mi base de datos.si alguien pudiese ayudarme a coooregir el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el **link** a la **documentación** y como se debería pasar los datos de manera correcta.

Pasar los datos:

```
$product = $repository->findOneBy(['name' => 'Keyboard']);
```

Adaptalo a tú necesidad

[**Documentacíon**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso sería algo como así:

```
$urldb = $repository->findOneBy(['url' => $url]);
```